# Calculating temperature from molecular dynamics simulation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, simulations

My understanding is that temperature is an inherently macroscopic quantity, but I've seen a number of people talk about calculating the temperature of ideal-gas simulations like [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion#/media/File:Translational_motion.gif). To take one example, in the final simulation [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) the author, a physicist, mentions calculating the pressure and temperature of the particles in his simulation.

Is it possible to define temperature for such a system, and to calculate it within a simulation? And how would one go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

The instantaneous temperature of a system of $N$ particles of masses $m_i$ and velocities $v_i$ is

$$ T(t) = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{m_iv_i^2(t)}{k_BN_f} $$

where $N_f$ equals the number of degrees of freedom, typically $N_f=3N-3$ for fixed total momentum.

Note that the instantaneous temperature will fluctuate 5-10% about the true (thermodynamic) temperature and should therefore be time-averaged.

Comment: thanks. Could you link a reference for how one derive this, and shows it is consistent with macroscopic definitions in the limit? Also does it only apply to free particles?

Comment: @tom A basic derivation can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory#Temperature_and_kinetic_energy) or in most resources on kinetic theory. For something citable I recommend the book [Understanding Molecular Simulation by Frenkel & Smit](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=5qTzldS9ROIC&oi=fnd&pg=PP2&dq=understanding+molecular+simulation&ots=nFMP0u4bSg&sig=AQVCDxrgiuDX5Az1exgNOrQYlMM#v=onepage&q=understanding%20molecular%20simulation&f=false). This result is not limited to free particles; it is used in force-based molecular dynamics simulations too.

Comment: why would you need to average over time to make it "physically-meaningful"?

Comment: @gatsu In the case of free particles it's not necessary, but it is when force fields are included since the temperature will fluctuate about the (physically-meaningful) average.

Comment: @lemon: yes the temperature will fluctuate and so what? Is there any principle in physics that forbids the temperature to fluctuate? Note that I have nothing against looking at averages. I just disagree with the fact that only the (time) average of what you call the instantaneous temperature is physically-meaningful.

Comment: @gatsu But temperature is a state function and is therefore an ensemble-averaged quantity, is it not? Moreover, it is the average that experimentalists measure.

Comment: @lemon: Temperature is a thermodynamic variable yes. But so is the volume (that fluctuates in the isobaric ensemble) or the internal energy (that fluctuates in the canonical ensemble). My only point is that it's not because a variable fluctuates that it loses its meaning. Moreover, the instantaneous temperature you defined is already an average (arithmetic mean of the kinetic energy per particle) which, in my view, provides already the (physical) meaning you seek.

Comment: I have reworded the last paragraph to eliminate the 'physically-meaningful' phrase, although I re-iterate that it is the average that is experimentally measured.

Comment: $N_f = 3N - N_c - N_r$ where $N_c$ are the geometrical constraints and $N_r$ depends on boundaries and the existence/absence of random forces. The expression $3N-3$ by Frenkel and Smit gives infinite temperature for a single particle in a box!

Comment: @juanrga Temperature is undefined for a single particle in a box (even if periodic).

Comment: @lemon there is no reason why temperature cannot be defined for few or even a single particle, but that wasn't my point. My remark was that the formula in Frenkel and Smit book gives an infinite temperature when N=1, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @lemon re-reading Frenkel and Smit, they introduce the temperature of a single particle on equation 4.2.1 $\langle v_\alpha^2 \rangle = k_\mathrm{B} T/m$ where, I quote them, "_$v_\alpha$ is the $\alpha$ component of the velocity of a given particle._"

Comment: This expression of instantaneous temperature is just the equipartition theorem: Each parabolic energy, has average kinetic energy kT. However, this would mean The ensemble/time average of instantaneous temperature is true temperature only for system with parabolic energy terms like Einstein solid or ideal gas.
What's wrong with the above reasoning?

Answer (score 2):

While lemon's answer is of course correct, it is not the only way to calculate the temperature from a molecular dynamics simulation: it can also be obtained from the configurations, that is, the particle coordinates, of the system. This is called "configurational temperature" (see, e.g., [this article](http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.62.4757); pay-walled). The key identity is (for a canonical ensemble)
$$k_\mathrm{B}T = \frac{\langle \mathbf B(\mathbf \Gamma) \cdot \nabla_{\mathbf \Gamma} H(\mathbf \Gamma) \rangle_{\mathbf \Gamma}}{\langle \nabla_{\mathbf \Gamma} \cdot \mathbf B(\mathbf \Gamma) \rangle_{\mathbf \Gamma}}$$
with $B$ an (almost; weak restrictions apply) arbitrary vector field depending on the phase space variables $\Gamma$, $H(\Gamma)$ the Hamiltonian and $\nabla_\Gamma$ the phase space gradient.$\langle \ldots \rangle_\Gamma$ denotes the ensemble average. The fact that $B(\Gamma)$ is basically arbitrary means that you can have $B$ also only depend on the positions and not on the momenta. For example, for $\mathbf B(\mathbf \Gamma) = \nabla E(\mathbf x)$ with $E(\mathbf x)$ being the system's potential energy, the following identity holds:
$$k_\mathrm{B} T = \frac{\langle \nabla E(\mathbf x) \cdot \nabla E(\mathbf x) \rangle}{\langle \nabla \cdot \nabla E(\mathbf x)\rangle}$$
Now $\langle \ldots \rangle$ just denotes the ensemble average with respect to the positions $\mathbf x$.
These and similar, only position-dependent, expressions are especially useful when you do Monte Carlo simulations where you usually don't have access to the kinetic energy of your system (note that this example is especially convenient for MD because you have to calculate $\nabla E(\mathbf x) = -\mathbf F(\mathbf x)$ anyway). The configurational temperature can also be used to estimate interaction potentials, that is, more than one "temperatures", see [this article](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/ct400580p) (pay-walled; disclaimer: one of the authors is my PhD supervisor).

Comment: That configurational temperature is not an instantaneous temperature, and only agrees with the kinetic *average* temperature under certain limits.